# Need div positioned right beside the UL - CSS

Tags: css

You can see the implementation here: http://jsfiddle.net/DVp4A/

How do I get the div 'quota info' to be situated to the top left of the UL?

I have the positioning of the UL stuff fine, I just don't know how to get the positioning of the 'quota-info' div to be top left and not 'above' the UL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to acomplish, try adding this this:

```
#quota-info {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}


#navigation {
    position:relative;
}
```

If it's not what you want to get let me know and try describe it as I'm an idot ;)

Comment: This looks like a good start. One thing I would like is for the breaks to not produce such large spaces between the lines. How do I reduce those altogether?

Comment: Don't use <br/>. Use div insteed: <div id="quota-info"><div>This is where Quote Info goes</div><div>Projects: 3/10</div></div> and in css: #quota-info div { height:20px; } I'm going to bed now, good night and good luck with your project! :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand exactly what is your requirement but check this http://jsfiddle.net/DVp4A/2/

If this is what you needed, I added

```
position:relative;
top:50px;
```

for `#quota-info`. If this is not what you need, please clarify or make visual example to help you.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining clearer. What I needed was for the 'quota-info' block to be on the same line as the navigation div. Marek's solution seems to work. Thanks.